# On fedora 24(guest os),can't install vmware tools to share files

Tags: vmware-tools

while using the vmware tools distributed with the vmware player 12, it always came the error 'unable to start vmware-tools.service execution aborted', no matter what way I tried(even reinstalled the guest os). Finally I gave up and tried to use the open-vm-tools distributed with the fedora os. It is so simply working just by typing a command! Like this:

vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs

and then I found my shared folder name in hgfs!
Amazing!
If you're still puzzled by the official vmware-tools, and driven crazy by all kinds of weird issues it has caused, maybe you could try this way.
Just one step to share your files between host os and guest os.
PS:The way to set the shared folder is omitted.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. If you want to share information here, you need to first write a question asking about a problem, which you can then answer in the space provided for answers below. This isn't a blog where you can just write an article. The [help] has more information about how the site works.

Comment: sorry, I'll pay attention to that next time.

Comment: No. :-) You need to pay attention to it **this time**. Please [edit] your question to make it a question, and post the answer below in the space headed *Your Answer*. If you don't want to do so, the alternative is to delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Fedora 24 already ships with an open-source version of vmware tools, called open-vm-tools (and open-vm-tools-desktop). One way you can access shared folders is by opening a terminal and typing the following (as root)

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs
```

Then, your shared folders should be accessible in the hgfs folder.